# systemd service file Failed to execute command: Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, digital-ocean, systemd

I am creating the `systemd service file` on a DigitalOcean Server which has has ubuntu 18 and NGINX as a web server.

The script at `systemd service file` is:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/computationalMarketing
ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/code/computationalMarketing/gunicorn --access-logfile --bind unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock computationalMarketing.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The error log is:

```
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of gunicorn.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-07-03 11:57:19 UTC; 10s ago
  Process: 8446 ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 8446 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Starting gunicorn daemon...
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[8446]: gunicorn.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[8446]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step USER spawning /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate: No such process
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 03 11:57:19 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
root@tfm-rius:/var/www/computationalMarketing/computationalMarketing/code/computationalMarketing#
```

Is this error related with the user used at service body, or maybe with one of the execStart command?

**Edit:**

I changed the user at service body to: `www-data`

Now, the log error is: `gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied`

Which user should be used? How can I correct this error?

**Edit2**

As Oliver says in the comments I exec:

```
ls -la /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
```

The output is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2243 Jun 28 10:11 /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
```

I have two ExecStart due I have to activate the virtualenv first and then activate gunicorn to allow app to work.

Log after execute: `chmod 755 /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate`

```
gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-07-06 20:39:45 UTC; 9s ago
  Process: 3472 ExecStart=/var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 3472 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Starting gunicorn daemon...
Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[3472]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: Exec format error
Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[3472]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate: Exec format error
Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 06 20:39:45 tfm-rius systemd[1]: Failed to start gunicorn daemon.
```

Comment: As root, what's the output of `ls -la /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate` ? Also, you have `ExecStart` twice in your script, sure the first entry is correct?

Comment: @Oliver I have edited the question to provide answer to your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Try `chmod 755 /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate`, it doesn't have `x` set so it can't be executed.

Comment: @Oliver Done, now the error is another one. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what error is but I'm also not sure if you can first activate the virtualenv and then run your python script, expecting the virtualenv to still be activated. I'd search for `systemd execute python with virtualenv` and see what other people do in this case.

Comment: And then what's the best solution? Install all outside virtualenv?

Comment: From a quick glance at the search results it looks like people activate the virtualenv and execute their program in one step and that seems to work.

Answer (score 4):

If SELinux is enforcing that would causing Exec/203 error.
You could check and fix as follows:

```
getenforce
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
ls -lZ /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
restorecon -vF /var/www/computationalMarketing/bin/activate
```